QGIS using Geometry Generator to connect multiple points within a layer separately
I have a CSV layer containing roughly 50,000 individual point vectors of vessel tracking data. The attribute columns are date/time, latitude, longitude, vessel ID and vessel name. Some vessels have tracks containing 10 points, some contain many more. Other vessels have multiple tracks covering different date/times.
I would like to connect these points so that I can see individual vessel tracks on individual dates/times. Is there a way I can make the geometry generator do this? I used the "Points to path" tool which kind of worked but it connected all the points as opposed to leaving them separate. I classified the layer in symbology by Vessel Name which allowed me to see the tracks easier but they obviously remained as points where I would like lines. I could split the whole layer into individual vessels and then run the points to path tool on each one but given the size of the data that would take some time.
I would screenshot what I'm talking about however the data is extremely sensitive so I am limited to what I can share, apologies.

What do you consider as an individual date/time? Tracks made on the same day?

Points to path tool allows you to group points, e.g.based on vessel ID or name, so that you get individual lines for each vessel separately. Use path group expression for that. See documentation for Points to path.
To get separate lines for the same vessel on different dates, use a combination of vessel ID and date as path group expression, e.g. concatenate them.
Be sure you don't have checked the box Create closed paths.
Point layer including two vessles (A and B), resulting in two separate, unconnected lines:

If you want to create separate lines for the same vessels, but different routes, concatenate two fields in the path group expression, e.g. like here: vessel || day(date) - in my case, vessel is the vessel-id, date is a datetime field and day() is the function to retrieve the day form datetime. So for each day and each vessel, a separate path will be generated:
Vessel A (blue) in the first route on April 19 (light blue) and April 25 (dark blue) and vessel B (red) on route on May erd only:


Hello Babel, I tried putting date/time in "Order expression" and vessel ID in "Path Group Expression" which connected the right points but it also linked them all to each other as though it is one continuous line. I tried them vice-versa which looked similar but didn't even link the right points. Any other ideas?

Can you share a sample of your data?
